# Does KafkaProducer onCompletion() callback always execute in the same thread?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

Kafka API 0.10.1 : [Link](https://kafka.apache.org/090/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html)

Is there any guarantee that onCompletion callback is called sequentially in the same thread? The documentation says "Note that callbacks will generally execute in the I/O thread of the producer". So I would think no.

If I want to keep track , for example, the number of exceptions that occurred by keeping an integer counter, do I need to use an AtomicInteger?

Or if I want to keep a boolean flag to keep track whether in  the last callback an exception occurred, would I need to make it volatile?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any guarantee that onCompletion callback is called sequentially in the same thread? The documentation says "Note that callbacks will generally execute in the I/O thread of the producer". So I would think no.

In general no. For example, per default there are multiple in-flight request in parallel -- it also depends on your number of retries (default is not retries).

> If I want to keep track , for example, the number of exceptions that occurred by keeping an integer counter, do I need to use an AtomicInteger?

There is only one thread writing. So strictly no. The reading thread might "miss" an update, but you will read this update later on.

> Or if I want to keep a boolean flag to keep track whether in the last callback an exception occurred, would I need to make it volatile?

Might be helpful.

Furthermore: You can just "block and wait" in your main thread for the callback.

For more details, see 
http://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/producer.html#synchronous-writes

Comment: So what you are saying is I should remove the callback and instead do future.get() ?

Comment: If you want to get sync processing, yes. It will of course come with a performance hit.

Comment: Right, this should really be a comment, no an answer. I am not looking for an alternative, just want to check if I should keep variables atomic/volatile or not.